# did or had done

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-participles

1a) I didn't know what he did.

1b) I didn't know what he'd done.

The context is "He stole from my house, and I didn't know it at the time of speaking" what would I use? Do they both mean the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

did is simple past, had done is past perfect. Either is correct in this sentence, depending on the rest of the paragraph. It is vital to keep tenses the same in writing fiction or nonfiction. Mixed tenses make reading difficult and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: "I didn't know what he had done." It helps me to think of it as" 'I didn't know what he had already done.'. Hope that helps.

Comment: can't we use "did" past simple here? I've heard when timeline is clear we can use past simple instead of past perfect. Same with the sentence "I knew what she did/had done" I want to use "did" but I am not sure if its correct

Comment: I didn't know he slapped you or he had slapped you. I think we can use either here so why can't we use "did" when timeline is clear here?

Comment: At the time of the burglary "I didn't know what he was doing". Afterwards "I didn't know what he had done" (past action with relevance to the present).

Comment: I didn't know what he did. what does it mean then? can we use it interchangeably in this sentence with had done?

Comment: he did something bad and when I met him I didn't know what he did/had done. what would i use here?

Comment: When I talked to him I didn't know what he did/had done later i found out he robbed/had robbed a bank. here can you tell plz if both past simple and perfect is correct here?

Comment: can i plz get answers?

Comment: Can you guys please answer me? I can give more examples "he was sorry for what he did/had done" do they both mean the same thing? if yes then what's the difference? context: he slapped me and later he was sorry for that so what would i use here past simple or perfect?

Comment: plz I need answers.